# PCI hardware access speeds - Kernel vs user space

Tags: kernel-modules, pci

Hi there Linux experts!

I'm trying to find the best way possible to control and stress a PCI device.
I've started off with writing a simple bash script that uses the commands from pciutils (lspci & setpci) to configure the device and create traffic on the bus

While the scripts work just fine, their execution speed seems much slower than the PCIe link speeds, making it hard to create stress on the bus, or quickly change between power modes and link speeds.

I was wondering, if ill write a kernel module that will call functions from the pci.h library, will its execution be faster? Will I be able to achieve faster access to the PCI device?

Any help would be much much appreciated :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stress the PCI device"? Access the configuration space (which is what pci.h does)? Do bus transfers to the device itself? You can do the latter via `/sys/devices/pci.../.../resource...` for the appropriate memory mapped range, no need to write a kernel module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a huge amount of overhead in the shell calling external commands to do anything. Fork/exec has a relatively high overhead.

Just moving from a shell script to a userspace C program using the API directly (instead of by calling CLI utilities) will be a huge speedup. Also easier than writing a kernel module. If you can find API bindings for a scripting language (Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.) then that'd be nearly as fast.

There is still overhead left (e.g., syscall overhead) that you could remove by then converting to a kernel module. At that point, you've eliminated essentially all the overhead and the only way you'd get faster would be getting rid of the operating system and/or custom test hardware.

PS: Questions about how to actually write the userspace C program or the kernel module are probably better asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), the Stack Exchange network site for programming questions. As with any Stack Exchange site, please check their [Stack Overflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting a question there. Theirs especially has some useful tips on asking a well-received question.